# Merge JSON Files via Bash or JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I've go files containing compressed JSONs. All JSONs having the same root fragments "id" and "test":

```
file1.json:
{"test":{"a":2},"id":"850303847"}
{"test":{"a":3},"id":"2742540872"}
{"test":{"a":4},"id":"1358887220"}

file2.json:
{"test":{"b":3},"id":"850303847"}
{"test":{"b":3},"id":"2742540872"}
{"test":{"b":4},"id":"1358887220"}

file3.json
{"test":{"c":8},"id":"850303847"}
{"test":{"c":4},"id":"2742540872"}
{"test":{"c":5},"id":"1358887220"}
```

I would like to merge these Files based on it's IDs resulting to:

```
{"test":{"a":2,"b":3,"c":8},"id":"850303847"}
{"test":{"a":3,"b":3,"c":4},"id":"2742540872"}
{"test":{"a":4,"b":4,"c":5},"id":"1358887220"}
```

I've looked into `jq -s` option for this but fail to find a way. Any ideas how to achieve in Bash (with or without JQ)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `reduce` all `inputs` into an object with `.id` as key, deep-merge using `*`, then iterate over the fields `.[]` to obtain a stream again (use the `-c` flag for compact output):

```bash
jq -nc 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; .[$i.id] |= (. // {}) * $i) | .[]' file*.json
```

```json
{"test":{"a":2,"b":3,"c":8},"id":"850303847"}
{"test":{"a":3,"b":3,"c":4},"id":"2742540872"}
{"test":{"a":4,"b":4,"c":5},"id":"1358887220"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jwv8RuOYJuM)

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```bash
jq -nc '
reduce inputs as {$test, $id} ({};
  .[$id] += $test
)
| keys_unsorted[] as $id
| {test: .[$id], $id}' files...
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WknYLLZKi2n)</sup>

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thanks!